# Has there been a change in Create DMP Segment API response header wrt segment ID : "X-LinkedIn-Id"?

Tags: linkedin-api

As We implemented our code long back where we used to get the value of SegmentID from "X-LinkedIn-Id" Attributes and now this attribute has been changed to all small letters and our code is not working due to this. Is this a temporary change or a permanent change? ***Depending on this we need to do backport to our previous releases so its very important to get this clarity***. And also we did not get any supporting doc related to this change over the official doc.
[image]

Can you please let us know about this so that we can make our final changes And also can you please share a doc wrt change logs on this API ?

And there is also a discrepancy around "x-linkedin-id" as in Docs, where its small letters and in git repo its still caps which we are currently using and facing the issue. Ref below:

**In the Doc related to Create DMP Segment**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/matched-audiences/create-and-manage-segments?tabs=http#create-dmp-segment , *"x-linkedin-id"* attribute is used.

**In Git Repo**

https://linkedin.github.io/rest.li/spec/protocol , *"X-LinkedIn-Id"* attribute is used.

Comment: Why not ask LinkedIn about this?

Comment: LinkedIn support has moved to stackoverflow and we need to add a tag #linkedin so that LinkedIn Eng can take a look and ans it.

Comment: Just have a look at the description of the tag at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin - the support has **not** moved to Stackoverflow

Comment: **In an effort to boost support for our developer community, we moved our online support forum from the Developers site to StackOverflow.
Before asking LinkedIn API-related questions at StackOverflow, be sure to:Tag question with the #linkedin hashtag so LinkedIn engineers will see them.
Read StackOverflow's How to Ask Good Questions guide.
Remember that StackOverflow is for technical questions and answers. For general questions about LinkedIn, please use the LinkedIn Help Center.** This is comment from LinkedIn Support Team

Comment: Whatever LinkedIn told you: StackOverflow can **not** handle their API support. If they change something in their API, you have to ask **them** about the reason